# ubuntu 14.04 traffic shaping

Tags: networking, ubuntu, traffic-shaping

Traffic shaping using htb and tc does not give expected results for shaping.

Hi I am using the script from [shaping](http://www.topwebhosts.org/tools/traffic-control.php)

```
$TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD
```

When I specify 0.5mbit as $DNLD the rate is being set as 250KB/s

I even tried to use wonder shaper. No matter what value I put for download and upload rate. It is defaulting to 50KB/s using wondershaper.

```
sudo wondershaper eth0 5120 5120     yields 50KB/s
```

If I don't use any TC or wonder shaper my speed is around 5MB/s

Am I setting something wrong?